# How to make system continute with same audio device after resume from suspend to RAM?

Tags: 20.04, sound, usb, pulseaudio, xfce

I have to unbind a USB audio device due to [bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1855678) before suspending, so a sink with different number is created during resume. I also have another audio device. How can you make system continue with the same device that was default/used before suspending? I have to run commands concerning pulseaudio as non-root. Or is it somehow possible to handle it so that the USB device does not have to be unbind so that the sink does not change?